# I can't find a way to run this counter 3 times in simultaneous with threads on the same compiling screen

Tags: c++, c++11

I can't find a way to run this counter 3 times in simultaneous with threads on the same compiling screen

I have already tried tons of solutions and can't find one yet

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        thread Para(Contatore);
        thread Para1(Contatore);
        Para.join();
        Para1.join();
    return 0;
}

void Contatore(){

    for(int i(0);i<=c;i++){
        cout<<i;
        if(i>=10){
            cout<<"\b\b";
        }else{
            cout<<"\b";
        }
    sleep(1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] that gets as far as you can, as well as your explaination of what you are trying, the error message or wrong behavior, and what you don't understand.

Comment: It looks like it does 2 times currently. Other than that, does it do what you want? If so make it do 3 times?

Comment: I would like a Compilation Screen with 3 different counters going simultaneously from 0 to a c const  with threads, cause now my program only does 2 counters but not in simultaneous, it waits for one to finish and then the other starts